# Update multiple rows to NULL when NOT NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL Server 2012 - I'm trying to update a column to NULL where the column has a value in it and is meeting other conditions, but I always get error:

> The subquery returned more than one value. This is not allowed if the subquery follows =,! =, <, <=,> Or> = or is used as an expression.

Here is what I tried so far:

```
UPDATE tblUsers
SET MobilePhoneNumber = CASE WHEN MobilePhoneNumber IS NOT NULL THEN NULL
                             ELSE MobilePhoneNumber
                        END
WHERE IsDisabled = 1
  AND ValidTo IS NOT NULL
  AND Id IN (SELECT Id FROM tblUsers
             WHERE IsDisabled = 1 AND ValidTo IS NOT NULL)

UPDATE tmp
SET MobilePhoneNumber = NULL
FROM tblUsers tmp
    INNER JOIN tblUsers tu ON tmp.Id = tu.Id
WHERE tmp.IsDisabled = 1 AND tmp.ValidTo IS NOT NULL
    AND tmp.MobilePhoneNumber IS NOT NULL
```

Please advice.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Neither of the queries you have shown should generate this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try like below

```
 UPDATE tblUsers 
 SET MobilePhoneNumber = null
  WHERE  
  Id IN (SELECT Id FROM tblUsers WHERE IsDisabled = 1 AND ValidTo IS NOT NULL)
  and MobilePhoneNumber is not null
```